# Tablesorter not working in IE7,8

Tags: jquery, tablesorter

I have a little problem - If you take a look at (With IE7 og IE8) : http://www.penst.dk/Tilsyn-og-kontrol/Tilsyn-og-kontrol-kommuner/Kommunalt-raadighedstilsyn/Resultater-raadighedstilsyn.aspx

And wanna sort on ex: "Fejlprocent", then it sorts 
72
42
38
37
37
36
3
29

That not correct, as 3 is lower than 29...
Any ideas how solve the issue? Im calling the function like:

```
$(".tablesorter").tablesorter({ sortList: [[0, 0], [1, 0]] });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because it's sorting based upon it being a string, you can give table sorter heading hints.

http://tablesorter.com/docs/example-meta-parsers.html

If you take a look in the development js file, search for

> // add default parsers

This will give you a clue as to which one's are available and how to write a custom one.

Comment: Look at the link I just posted.

Comment: Then for to sort is as a number, it would be: {sorter: 'number'} ? or {sorter: 'int'} ?

Comment: I've updated the post to help you, I think it's digit though.